# HELP Distribution of the Minimum of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Well Let $Y$ be a random variable that could be discrete or continuous and $M$ a positive constant random variable Find the distribution of $S$$=$$min${Y,M}

My progress so far is :

$p($S $<x$)$=$$p($$min${Y,M} < $x$)$=$ $1-$p($min${Y,M}>$x$)=$1-$p($Y>x,M>x$) But then I am not sure how to keep going so I don´t know if this is the right way to begin,If anyone could give me an Idea or help me I really would appreciate

Comment: CAPS ARE NOT A GOOD WAY OF GETTING ASSISTANCE ON THIS SITE, OR IN LIFE IN GENERAL.

Comment: What are CAPS ??? I'm Sorry ,any way, I really hate to ask for help but I am desperate

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to begin. Now, if $M$ is constant, then the event $\{ M > x \}$ is either always true or never true (almost surely). You should distinguish two cases, $x \leq M$ and $x > M$.

Comment: But what about S? ,if M is false then we have Fs(x) for x<M       right ? but if it is true ??

Comment: Let's say $M$ is constant. The event $\{ Y > x \} \cap \{ M > x \}$ equals $\{ Y > x \}$ if $M > x$ and $\emptyset$ if $M \leq x$. So the cumulative distribution function of $S$ is
$$ P(S \leq x) = P(Y \leq x) \ \text{ if } \ x < M \ \ \text{ and } \ \  P(S \leq x) = 1 \ \text{ if } \ x \geq M.   $$

Answer (score 0):

$$p(S<x)=p(Y < x \cup M < x)=p(Y<x)+p(M<x)-p(Y<x,M<x)$$
Notice ([*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability)): $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, where A and B are any events.